# How to use delayed job for a method in ActiveModel (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, activemodel, rails-activejob

I have a controller as

```
class Api::V2::Events::WegSessionsController < Api::V2::Events::ApplicationController

def synchronize
 if @service.valid_connection?
  @service.delay.synchronize
   render json: {
    status: :ok,
    message: @service.message
  }, status: :ok
else
  render json: {
    status: :unprocessable_entity,
    errors: @event.errors.full_messages
  }, status: :ok
 end
 ..Service instantiation and other code
 end
end
```

and the service class looks like

```
class WegService
include ActiveModel::Model

def synchronize
 if event.weg_synced_at.present?
  update
 else
  create
 end

 event.update(weg_synced_at: Time.current)
end
...Some code
end
```

But I am not able to execute this since my method @service.delay.synchronize is throwing an error.

```
<ArgumentError: job cannot be created for non-persisted record:
```

What should I do here?

Comment: Can you give full details of the error?

Comment: Not an error as such. I am just getting the entire data in the console when I run @service.delay.synchronize without really executing the method

Comment: But my trivial question is, can we run the delay on a method in a service class that implements an ActiveModel?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Have you got delayed_job daemon running?  Also, when is the Service message set?  If it's in the  `syncrhonize` method then it may not be available when you render the json. Your "error" sounds like a normal response from an iteration.

Comment: I am actually getting the error <ArgumentError: job cannot be created for non-persisted record:

Comment: Ah, right, of course.  You can't pass model instances to delayed job if they haven't been saved, because the model is passed via id.  You''d need to do `@service.save; @service.delay.syncrhonize` but that means your synchronise logic needs to change as well.